# DEM derived from LiDAR in wrong location

Tags: arcmap, dem, lidar

I am trying to derive slope and aspect from a DEM that was derived over a mine using LiDAR in ArcMap v 10.8.1 . However, the DEM seems to be in the wrong location (further North from the Area of Interest). I unfortunately don't have access to the LAS file or the data custodians.

I have tried both the "Project Raster" and "Define Projection" tools to change the coordinate system but the DEM is still in the incorrect location. The current projection is:

[image]

Comment: It's exceedingly difficult to figure out what went wrong in a spatial reference mixup without details about the before and after.

Comment: Do you know for sure which crs is correct?

Comment: If you feel the dataset is correct maybe your map is in another coordinate system and you have not set the transformation?